# Polar representation of an horizontal line

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates, image-processing

I'm studying the Hough transform which is an algorithm for finding lines in images. In general it is common to use the Polar representation $\left(d = x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta)\right)$ of the line, due to the problems caused by the vertical lines in the cartesian representation ($Y = aX + b$, vertical lines have a tending to infinity).

But when implementing this algorithm I figured out that the horizontal lines cause problems to Polar form due to $\sin(0)\to\infty$. So, how to represent a horizontal line in a polar form using this equation: $$Y = \frac{d - X\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}?$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t really see a problem here.

Calling your equation a “polar representation” of the line is something of a misnomer, I think, and might be causing some confusion. You’re still working in Cartesian, not polar, coordinates. Your equation is just the general equation $ax+by=d$ of a line in the plane with the coefficients normalized so that $a^2+b^2=1$. (This makes the normal vector $(a,b)$ a unit vector.) It looks like the parameter $\theta$ measures the angle that the line makes with the $x$-axis, with positive angles measured clockwise, which is a somewhat unconventional choice, but likely makes sense in context.

The Cartesian equation of a horizontal line is simply $y=d$, and this is entirely compatible with your representation: just set $\theta=\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, amd. You are right in your definitions, however, I'm with other doubt. How to do the same with a vertical line (X = d), which theta = 0?

Comment: @FelippeTrigueiro Again, there’s no problem: $\cos 0=1$ and $\sin 0=0$, so the equation becomes $x=d$ as required. The point of using this general form of equation is that all lines on the plane can be represented in this form, without exception. That’s not true of the slope-intercept form.

Answer (score 0):

An horizontal line is a line of the form $x=k$. Since, in polar coordinates, $x=\rho\cos\theta$, that line is represented, in polar coordinates, by$$\rho=\frac k{\cos\theta}.$$

Comment: Unless the line passes through the origin.